# Calling a certificate to use as authentication for download

Tags: r, authentication, proxy, certificate

I'm trying to create a download tool that downloads multiple data files at numerous links from a single database that requires a username/password.

To be specific, these are netcdf files and when I am logged into the database, I can simply enter this URL, hit enter, and automatically download this data:
*https://vesg.ipsl.upmc.fr/thredds/dodsC/GeoMIP/output/IPSL/IPSL-CM5A-LR/rcp45/3hr/atmos/3hr/r1i1p1/v20130428/vas/vas_3hr_IPSL-CM5A-LR_rcp45_r1i1p1_200601010300-205601010000.nc.dods?vas[0][0][0]*

I'm trying to automate this process so I don't have to go to the database website and log in. I have tried using the *username:password@ above URL* approach but I receive an HTML 500 error. So, I'm trying to use a certificate.

Using R.Utils, I entered in the server, username and password of the database. I was able to create what I think is a certificate (called 'C%3A') that should pass along my credentials. 'C%3A' seems to be an HTML file. Is this a certificate containing my credentials? If so;

How do I call this 'certificate' so that the individual URLs that I try to collect the data from know that I have the authorization to download this data?

Comment: What exactly is the code you've tried? Are you sure those servers support client certificates for authentication? That seems very unusual.

Comment: @MrFlick My code is set to download a list of URL files. However, because this database is protected by scientists, you need to request a username and password to call the data. If I run my code without any certificate authentication, I receive a very long error that starts as "syntax error, unexpected SCAN_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or SCAN_ERROR". So I need a certificate to access the data. The server does support client certificates, but I'm not sure how to call the certificate in the first place

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense to me. What R functions are you using specifically?

Comment: @MrFlick So I'm working on downloading a netcdf file from this database. So, for example, when I have my credentials entered in on the website, I can simply enter this url and download the data: 

https://vesg.ipsl.upmc.fr/thredds/dodsC/GeoMIP/output/IPSL/IPSL-CM5A-LR/rcp45/3hr/atmos/3hr/r1i1p1/v20130428/vas/vas_3hr_IPSL-CM5A-LR_rcp45_r1i1p1_200601010300-205601010000.nc.dods?vas[0][0][0]

However, I need to be able to download this exact URL without first entering my information in the database. This is why I need a certificate to do so, because doing username:password@domain doesn't work